# H2O Mojo model always return the same value for prediction

Tags: java, prediction, h2o, mojo

I have trained a stacked ensemble model with automl() function provided by H2O (3.36.0.4)for R. Once the model is trained, i have exported it to .zip format with the download_mojo() function.

I have created a Java app following instructions, but when running the program, the model always predicts the same value.

This is the app developed in Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import hex.genmodel.easy.RowData;
import hex.genmodel.easy.EasyPredictModelWrapper;
import hex.genmodel.easy.prediction.*;
import hex.genmodel.MojoModel;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        EasyPredictModelWrapper model = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(MojoModel.load("StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily_8_AutoML_1_20220407_144828.zip"));

        BufferedReader csvReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dataset.csv"));
        RowData inputrow = new RowData();
        String row;
        String[] colnames = new String[36];
        String[] data;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            row = csvReader.readLine();
            if (i == 0) {
                colnames = row.split(",");
            } else {
                data = row.split(",");
                for (int k = 0; k < colnames.length - 2; k++) {
                    inputrow.put(colnames[k], data[k]);
                }
                RegressionModelPrediction prediction = model.predictRegression(inputrow);
                System.out.println("Prediction "+i+": " + prediction.value);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

It returns this:

```
Prediction 1: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 2: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 3: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 4: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 5: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 6: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 7: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 8: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 9: 0.09239077248718583
Prediction 10: 0.09239077248718583
```

For more details, training and test datasets have the same variables and the model have been trained with following parameters:

```
aml <- h2o::h2o.automl(y = y,
                       training_frame = df_h2o,
                       nfolds = 10,
                       max_models = 150,
                       max_runtime_secs = NULL,
                       keep_cross_validation_predictions = TRUE,
                       stopping_metric = 'RMSE',
                       sort_metric ='RMSE',
                       verbosity = "info")
```

And I have performed the following checks, with the same dataset used in java:

```
modelPath <- paste0(getwd(), "/StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily_8_AutoML_1_20220407_144828")
loaded_model <- h2o.loadModel(modelPath)


val_df <-  read.csv("dataset.csv")
input_row <- val_df[1:10 ,1:36]
new_data <- as.h2o(input_row)

h2omodel_preditions <-as.vector(h2o.predict(loaded_model, new_data, exact_quantiles=TRUE))


original_mojo_path <- paste0(getwd(), "/StackedEnsemble_BestOfFamily_8_AutoML_1_20220407_144828.zip")
mojo_model <- h2o.upload_mojo(original_mojo_path)
mojo_predictions  <- as.vector( h2o.predict(mojo_model, new_data))


> h2omodel_preditions
 [1] 0.27564401 0.25663341 0.17848737 0.05179671 0.02977053 0.28588998 0.29157313 0.19800770 0.06251480 0.23992213
> mojo_predictions
 [1] 0.27564401 0.25663341 0.17848737 0.05179671 0.02977053 0.28588998 0.29157313 0.19800770 0.06251480 0.23992213
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide more details? Does the original model create different predictions? Would you be able to put here the [info] part of model.ini from the root directory of the model archive (it shouldn't contain anything private)? Are the column names parsed from the csv the same as the ones used for model training? (e.g. does the parsed string contain quotes or spaces that aren't present when training)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe I have edited the question with the information you request.

Comment: Thank you for the details you added. It seems to me that the issue could be in the csv parsing - are you sure that the `colnames[...]` contain the same column names as was used during training? Even a space around comma or quotes could cause this. I think that the model doesn't really get the data (wrong names) and so it produces value that would be produced with input of missing values - you can try to do that in R (set values of all input columns to NA) and look at the predicted value - if I'm right it should be the same one (0.0923...). Otherwise I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right. There were double quotes in colnames. I have removed them and now it works correctly. Thanks!